# mysql procedure creation

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am creating a procedure in mysql as follows. H

```
DELIMETER $$
create procedure getname(IN rll int,OUT nm varchar(30))
BEGIN
select name into nm from student where roll=rll
END
$$
DELIMETER ;
```

However it is not working and I am getting the error message as follows:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimeter$$ create procedure getname(IN rll int,OUT nm varchar(30)) BEGIN select' at line 1.

Please suggest where I might be going wrong.

Comment: In the code above you have a space after the word "delimiter", in the error message, however, you do not. Which is the version you used?

Answer (score 1):

First, You have a syntax error in the word `DELIMETER $$`, please change it to `DELIMITER`

And you can try create procedure as described in [MySql documentations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html):

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure getname(IN rll int,OUT nm varchar(30))
BEGIN
select name into nm from student where roll=rll;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its `DELIMITER` not `DELIMETER` and also better to use `;` for the end of a statement like `select`

So the procedure will look like

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure getname(IN rll int,OUT nm varchar(30))
BEGIN
select name into nm from student where roll=rll ;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```